# Is it possible to type different value for multiple cursors?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext3, vscode-extensions

When doing multi cursor selection, often you need to type a different value for each, you've to cancel selection even though all cursors are where you want them to be.

Is it possible to activate some sort of mode and press tab to automatically iterate through each one by one on every tab and type your value. Esc to cancel the mode.

[image]

**Note:** how in end I had to type 1, 2, 3, 4 manually. Those could have been food categories, clothing size, select options etc.

Comment: Isn't the mult cursor purpose exactly that you type the same input in different positions? If you want one location to contain input1 and another input2 then click on location one and type input1 then click on location 2 and insert input2. Why would you need multi cursors for that at all?

Comment: @MikeLischke multiple cursor purpose is to be useful. Yes typing same thing is very helpful. But that's not all multiple cursors do. They let you cut and paste multiple different values but in same order as well. I updated answer to show what usefulness of this

Answer (score 7):

In case you don't want to install extension, you can copy sample data (which is generated by your favorite scripts or [tools](https://mytexttools.com/numbered-list-generator.html), for example) then paste it to the current cursors.

For example, I generate numbers by

##### JavaScript:

```
Array(10).fill(0).map((a, i) => i + 1).join('\n')
```

##### Or `shell / bash` script:

```bash
seq 10
```

Then,

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For the special case of when you want to insert values that follow a sequence at your multiple cursor locations, then the powerful [Insert Nums](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Insert%20Nums) package for Sublime Text can help.

Insert Nums can fill in numbered blanks (1,2,3,4, ... 10), and much more. Just about anything you could write as a for loop can be generated and inserted at the multiple cursors. This includes integer/float/string, count up/down, arbitrary start/stop/step values, and formatting to hex, binary, etc., representation. You can also evaluate an expression at each index, so for example you can create a geometric or power series or a pattern of bit shifts.

The default case for Insert Nums is integers, starting at 1, incrementing by 1, and ending when all selections are filled. For the example problem in the question of numbering `Items`, all you'd have to do is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, then <kbd>Return</kbd>. The numbers 1 through 5 would be filled in.

Answer (score 3):

[Text Pastry](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jkjustjoshing.vscode-text-pastry) is a vscode extension which does exactly these type of things.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer for Sublime, and there core Sublime can't do this out of the box, but you can add the capability to do it to via a third party package.

The [PowerCursors](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PowerCursors) package is one way to go with this. With it installed it's as simple as <kbd>Alt+[</kbd> and <kbd>Alt+]</kbd> to cycle between existing cursors (the binds use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> instead if you're on MacOS) and type what you like, amongst other capabilities.

There may well be other packages that incorporate something similar as well, so it may be worth casting around a little bit on [packagecontrol.io](https://packagecontrol.io/) to see what you can dig up.

Comment: while it's not for vscode, it's good to know im not going crazy here. So this confirms that this idea is out there and useful

Answer (score 0):

For **[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/)** editor, plugin "Carets Numbering" exists, which does this job. You enter starting number, etc, and it inserts increasing numbers at multi-carets positions.

[image]